# Push format of image while paste from clipboard

Tags: images, compression, copy-paste, clipboard

Problem: email client (theBat!) is using `jpg` for all images from clipboard. I need to use `png` or `gif` instead.
For now I can only save image to disk in needed format and insert through menu - very annoying procedure when create hundred messages per day...

- yes, there is no information about compressing in clipboard;
- Outlook is using `png` and offers great result quality-compression: I often paste screenshots and `gif/png` are the most suitable format;
- Excel is doing great with png as well without resizing;

Is there any way or program that will help me to avoid routine of saving images to disk and inserting them manually? Best way is to keep steps close to Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1) Clipboard always contains image in BMP format, and there is no information about compressing in clipboard.

2) You can use the Clipboard Stripper (http://clipboard-stripper.com/) to save images directly from clippboard in BMP/PNG/JPG format as you wish, and next insert it to the bat from file